# Breadth-first search on a tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, breadth-first-search

The following code performs breadth first search on a mockup tree

```
# some tree
#             A            - LAYER 0
#         B       C        - LAYER 1 
#      D     E             - LAYER 2
#   F                      - LAYER 3

def get_something(x):
    if x == 'a':
        return ['b', 'c']
    if x == 'b':
        return ['d', 'e']
    if x == 'c':
        return []
    if x == 'd':
        return ['f']
    if x == 'e':
        return []
    if x == 'f':
        return []
```

and it is traversed by the following not so beautiful code

```
# I mean it works, but looking at it makes me feel sick

def recursive_get(x, loop_limit, count_limit):

    # stop condition 1: loop limit exceeded and nonzero
    # stop condition 2: count limit exceeded and nonzero
    # stop condition 3: we have reached the bottom

    current = 0
    seen_list = []
    todo_list = [x]

    while ((current < loop_limit or loop_limit == 0) and
           (len(seen_list) < count_limit or count_limit == 0) and
           todo_list):

        result = get_something(todo_list.pop(0))
        seen_list.extend(result)
        todo_list.extend(result)
        current += 1

    return seen_list
```

Is there any syntactic sugar to get the second part to look more sexy? (less lines, syntactically nicer looking)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`get_something`** is not a good name for the function. Obviously, it specifies your tree by returning the child nodes of an argument node; rename to, say, **`get_neighbors`**. Also, your implementation overkills breadth-first search a bit. See what I mean:

```
def get_neighbors(x):
    if x == 'a':
        return ['b', 'c']
    if x == 'b':
        return ['d', 'e']
    if x == 'c':
        return []
    if x == 'd':
        return ['f']
    if x == 'e':
        return []
    if x == 'f':
        return []

    return [] # Other nodes have no neighbors.

def bfs(start):
    queue = [start]
    visited = set(start)

    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0)

        for neighbor in get_neighbors(node):
            if neighbor not in visited:
                queue.append(neighbor)
                visited.add(neighbor)

    return visited

print(str(bfs('a')))
```

Also, note that **`seen_list`** should be rather a Python **`set`** as operating on it is more efficient than on lists.

Comment: I would probably call it `getSiblings` or `getSibling` because of the fact there is only 1 neighbor/sibling. But I prefer sibling, especially if you are going to use the terms parent and child for nodes uphill or downhill.

Comment: In a tree, yes. As soon as we get to a graph, the colloquial name is **neighbors = children + parents** (in the case of undirected graph).

Comment: neighbors is the correct terminology for either a node tree or a graph

Comment: Not all operations on `set`s are more efficient. Adding an element should be faster with a normal list. For checks with `in` your statement is correct though.